# Any recommendations for setting up a campaign website?

Tags: vs-web-site-project

A friend of mine asked me to help her setup a website for her school board campaign. She wants to let people donate their time and money through the site. I don't want to go through much effort setting this up. I've integrated sites with payment API's in the past, and really don't want to do this.

Anyone have recommendations for a quick, easy, and cheap campaign site? I found a bunch when searching, but some are expensive while others are not. Any advice?

Comment: Well no responses to this. I found many many resources. Timing was really important. "I need this yesterday" kind of thing so I went with the FaceBook Donate button which uses First Giving. https://www.firstgiving.com/NpoSignup?&__hssc=&__hstc=&hsCtaTracking=63dc40dc-143f-4619-8011-3d1a09594d88|7a1ba0e5-61a3-4323-940b-cf2c3fe07175#0

Answer (score -1):

Good: Use Facebook, and skip the website entirely
•   Use Facebook “Donate” button to accept donations (supported by First Giving https://www.firstgiving.com/NpoSignup?&__hssc=&__hstc=&hsCtaTracking=63dc40dc-143f-4619-8011-3d1a09594d88|7a1ba0e5-61a3-4323-940b-cf2c3fe07175#0)
•   Use Facebook to communicate with supporters. People can just post on your Facebook page that they want to donate time. You can be notified, and keep track manually. 
•   Why choose this? By far the easiest and fastest setup, but is the least customized. First Giving looks a little pricey (7.5% per donation), but for the ease and timing it may be worth it. This could be setup this week, but you won’t have your own domain or website. To summarize: this will be really fast with a low startup cost, but the ongoing costs with First Giving will be higher. Choose this if this is a onetime thing for you. You might also choose this to get started, and then add a website later if you decide you need it.

Better: Setup a website, and use Facebook to let people donate time
•   Use BlueHost.com to host a WordPress website using a standard (free) theme $3.95 / month
•   Use Seamless Donations plugin for WordPress (requires a paypal payment account to receive donations in your bank account)
•   Domain Registration through Go Daddy. About $20 / year
•   Use “Call to Action” button on Facebook to lead people to donate $ on your website.
•   Why choose this? Relatively inexpensive, but the annual costs should be compared to the costs of First Giving in the “Good” scenario. This option requires some technical expertise getting your site up and running. Also, you will have to create the website from scratch. This sounds great, but if you’ve ever asked someone how it was to build their own house they will tell you there are decisions that need to be made that can be tedious and numerous. The WordPress theme will help a lot, and is basically a template to follow. I wouldn’t recommend getting custom with it. Just pick a theme you like, put in the words and pictures you want and get started. Then on Facebook you can direct people to your website with a call to action button (free). Choose this option if you think you’ll need to do this again, or just really want to have your own website and accept donations through it.

Best: Setup a custom WordPress website, use Facebook, and accept text message donations (SMS donations)
•   Similar to the “Better” scenario this really requires much more time to setup because it is highly customized.
•   I saw some Political WordPress themes for $50 https://colorlib.com/wp/political-wordpress-themes-for-politicians/, but if you want a custom site you’ll have to hire a graphical website designer. I can tell you that you can expect to spend $2000+ to get the custom site you want.
•   Why choose this? You want to accept donations in multiple formats including text messaging. https://mgive.com/ This makes it as easy as possible to donate money. The tradeoff is that the costs can be high, and timing long. If you plan on doing this for an extended period of time, or repeatedly all the effort might make sense.